# how to add multiple Owner in ADLDS groups

Tags: active-directory, ldap, adlds

I am new to this ADLDS ,Looking into this group ownership concept in ADLDs,
suppose I have a group, and I want set permission OWNER access to groups,
for multiple user, depend upon requirement.

I had checked ADLDS had groups owner, by default is Administrator, but didn't find any how to set Groups Owner in particular group,

using ADSI, or LDP.exe , how can I assign OWNER for group

what I need to configure,

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no GUI for what you're trying to do in ADSI. I'm not sure about LDP.

To accomplish what you're trying to do is you can use a tool called **`DSACLS`**

You can find this tool in this location:

> %WINDIR%\ADAM

### Viewing container permissions

> dsacls.exe \testserver:50000\CN=Users,CN=TestApp,O=Test

### Granting general permissions on a container

> dsacls.exe \testserver:50000\CN=TestApp,O=Test /I:T /G CN=MembershipProvider,CN=Roles,CN=TestApp,O=Test:GR

There are a couple of things to notice here. "/I:T" sets permissions to the container and its sub objects, while we could've used "/I:S" to include only the sub objects. "/G" means grant ("/D" is deny). The "user or group DN" is the distinguished name of the user, group or role that we grant access to the container. The "permission" part can be GR for read and GW for write (other more specific permissions are also available).

[This](http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=34) article explains more in depth...